# Change sign-on URLs for security purposes

Tags: login

For security reasons, it should be possible to rename login.php to something different, and change other access shortcuts (eg: wp-admin) to point to the new URL.

Is there a documented best practice for this? If not, what would the most correct methodology be?

I appreciate that this is not *security* per se, just obfuscation, but I'm considering this to be just another *layer* of protection: not a *replacement* of other security tactics such as failed attempt lockdown limiting and stricted password enforcement.

Creative approaches welcome.

Comment: Why _not about redirects or rewrites_?

Comment: This is not a security feature. See [Bruce Schneier: The Non-Security of Secrecy](http://www.schneier.com/essay-056.html). `wp-admin` is hard coded.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not security.  Besides. wp-admin and wp-login.php are hard coded -- you're not going to be able to change them unless you hack into the core.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the locations being hard-coded, though I think that there's probably some way out there that doesn't require changes to core in order to work (note the amount of user-authentication functions available in pluggable).

Comment: While I agree that "secrecy is not security", if you consider the number of installs of WP, all of which have the same login URL, it presents a significant target. Consider that your site, out of 60 million installs has a different login URL - you are now clearly off the radar of any hack bot. Obviously someone who specifically wants to hack your site will not be as deterred, but that's not really what my question was about.

Comment: @kaiser well, maybe I shouldn't have shut that door prematurely, but as far as I can tell, a redirect or rewrite won't solve the problem of someone going to myblog.com/wp-admin and A)determining it's a WP site and b)start hacking.

Comment: It's not really off the radar.  You're better off creating a plugin that enforces strict password rules -- not trying to hide a login page.  I don't need wp-admin to tell it's a wp site.  There are more than a few wonderful features for me to (a) figure that out and (b) start hacking should I choose to do so. The only way an attacker is likely to break in is via brute force password guessing. There are solutions for that: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-login-lockdown/

Comment: @christopherDavis - I agree with all your points, but there is one major reason why some people want to change the login URL and that is the use of BOTS or SCRIPTS that target the specific default wordpress login. it is not the case when a single hacker would target a single website. in that case - it is obviously useless because like you pointed out - knowing that a site runs wordpress is ridiculously easy in most cases. @ Tom Auger - every comment here is basically right.better focus on other security features, and I am not sure why you do not want redirect-rewrites - it is the easiest way.

Comment: Ok. I +1ed some of the comments above, but the _bot_ attack scripts is still valid. The link @toscho provided is a nice read. But why not add the extra level for the _dump_ attackers... and bots are _dump_ per default - they don't know anything about edge cases. Why? Because they work for 90% of all cases and that's enough. Therefore: Why discuss the _why_ and not the _how_?

Comment: @ChristopherDavis awesome, +1 for the plugin solution. Thanks for your perspective.

Comment: @krembo99, thanks for your input. Maybe I haven't thought through the redirect/rewrite option. Why don't you post an answer that addresses my original question using a redirect/rewrite approach and we'll see. I'll amend my post to remove that bit about redirects.

Comment: @kaiser thanks. My point precisely. Everyone seems to be focusing on putting down the idea of changing the default URLs, instead of considering it to be an _additional_ security measure. Like you said, knocking off 90% of "random" bot attackers. Still a security improvement if you ask me, and I never said that I would not implement additional security measures.

Comment: There's also one additional argument: What if `/wp-login.php` and `/wp-admin` doesn't fit your site concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge of course is not "breaking" or "hacking" core to do this.

Riffing off of krembo99's filter idea, I wonder whether the following wouldn't be a high-level approach to the solution from a plugin perspective:

1. copy wp-login.php to a new file in the root WP directory.
2. Use the `'login_url'` filter to point to this new file
3. Use the `'admin_url'` filter to point to a new "pseudo-url" for admin
4. Set up the `'login_init'` action to either just exit, or put up some default error screen, maybe redirect to the 404 page.
5. Edit the file you copied in step 1 and remove the `do_action( 'login_init' )` line (or replace it with a custom action of your own).

I haven't tested this - it's just a theory. The biggest challenge left is - when you upgrade WP - does it delete any files that it doesn't expect in the root? If so, the plugin will also have to check to see if WP has been upgraded and if so, re-install the alternative login file. And of course, we'd want it to be done by copying the newly-upgraded wp-login.php, so it would have to run a regexp search-and-replace on the `do_action( 'login_init' )` line.

Answer (score 4):

Well, considering rewrite and redirect like in comments -

choose  what fits you best .

**HOOK** wp_login_url();
 //this function generate the login url address

Example:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'another_login_url', 10, 2);
function another_login_url( $force_reauth, $redirect ){
    $login_url = 'your_chosen_login_url';

    if ( !empty($redirect) )
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $redirect ), $login_url );

    if ( $force_reauth )
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'reauth', '1', $login_url ) ;

    return $login_url ;
}
```

**Redirect** action

```
add_action( 'login_redirect', 'mysite_login_redirect');
function mysite_login_redirect(){
    return 'your_url';
}
```

.htaccess **rewrite URL**

```
RewriteRule ^login$ http://site.com/wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

.htaccess **redirect rule**

```
RewriteRule ^login$ http://site.com/wp-login.php [NC,L,R]
```

Personally I prefer the rewrite function

**add_rewrite_rule()**

```
add_action( 'init', 'k99_login_rewrite' );
function k99_login_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'login/?$', 'wp-login.php', 'top' );
}
```

NOTE : some of those methods can change according to wp version, but in the latest versions all should work.
THere are also other methods, if you find none of those suitable for you ..

Comment: Thanks for the response, Krembo. I might be completely misreading this stuff, so forgive me, but it looks like all of your answers but the first don't solve the problem (which is why I originally said "no rewrites" in my OP). The filter is a partial solution perhaps, though it doesn't address wp-admin (you need to use the 'admin_url' filter for that). All the others give you an ADDITIONAL URL you can type in that will take you to wp-login.php. But a hacker can still target wp-login.php directly.

Comment: This was an EXCELLENT answer. I found it right after I figured it out, but this was exactly how I did it minus the rewrite stuff.