# How to redirect user after session timeout

Tags: multisite, users, redirect

How can i redirect user after session timeout in multisite to my custom Page?

Normally Wordpress multisite redirects users to example.com/subdirectory/wp-login.php

Comment: Have you looked at tying this onto your function? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the `login_url`:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'wpse103239_login_url' );
function wpse103239_login_url() {
    return 'your-login-url';
}
```

See also [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43165/16121) for a bunch more options.

#### Reference

The `login_url` filter is mentioned in the Codex page for [`wp_login_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url), but there doesn't seem to be a Codex page for the filter itself.

Comment: No problem.  If my answer worked for you, please mark it Accepted.

Comment: I just added your code and I realized that I use it already for make the login mydomain.com/login .....so I think it has nothing to do with "session timeout"

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between "session timeout" and "need to log in".

Comment: ok ,in multisite When the session timeout ends the user is redirects to example.com/subdirectory/wp-login.php ...in my case I want to redirect my users to my login page example.com/login already set with your code